# UIScrollView Paging Enabled turning back to center view when clicked

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have a Scroll View with paging enabled. and a long width so i can select between my 3 pages. But Every time that i click somewhere on the left or right side it goes back to the middle view. how can i fix it? here's a video sample http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1bj7_CBt-g

and this is the code in my viewDidLoad for that paging function.

```
pageIndex = 0;
    self.myScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 320, 0, 0);
    self.myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.myScrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [self.myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 120)];
```

thank you for all your help!

Comment: Have you disabled bouncing feature of UIScrollView

Comment: Yes, but i still got the same

Comment: Do you have an custom touch handling? Can you paste some more code from your controller?

Comment: No i don't have any custom touch handling. That is the only code i got for my `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `self.myScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 320, 0, 0);`

Try `self.myScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`. I suspect it is the problem.

If you want to by default scroll to one page, you can use

```
[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:([Your rect]) animated:NO];
```

Comment: if i remove that my srollview will not be able to be a 3 page scrollview, it will become like a plain scroll view without pages. did you see the video? did you notice that it is in paging? if i remove that what can i do to make it like it is in paging?

Comment: Yes I know it is a paging scroll view. I guess you have tried it? I have a calendar view https://github.com/ethan-fang/DPCalendarthat uses exactly three paging scroll view and it works fine without setting contentInset. When you set contentInset, it will have a gap. And from your description, I deduce that is the problem. contentInset has nothing to do with paging.

Comment: I cannot download your calendar source code. thank you for your response i'll try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: Hi! i've tried your answer and this is what i get http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgisVwaXsNo the middle part cannot be "Snap" you know what i mean? it dont stop on the middle part.

Comment: The url is connect with "that", sorry. This is the url: https://github.com/ethan-fang/DPCalendar So previously you can not go to the boundary page but now you can not go to the middle. Your situation is really weird. Can you post more code so that I can get more information? Can you also try remove setting "contentInset" completely.

Comment: can you add me on skype? so i can send you the source code, so you can see for your self what is the weird problem? this is my skype "gps.ttttt" thanks!

Comment: i think the problem is in PagingEnabled. i tried to remove that my swiping in both sides wont get me back to the middle. but it doesn't "Snap" into position where the right color background is. please add me on skype so you can see the whole source code. "gps.ttttt"

Comment: Sorry I don't have skype. However I have email ethan.fang@hotmail.com :)

Comment: PLease check your emails :) i've attached the source code. thank you

Comment: Hi, I sent it back to you.

Comment: Yes i received it. and i replied, and i have more question :( please reply again :D but thank you very much. your solution worked!